# length of array in json string returns unexpected results in angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Vojislav Kovacevic",
        "street": "Sava Burica",
        "city": "Belgrade",
        "state": "Zemun",
        "zip": "11080",
        "country": "Serbia",
        "giftwrap": null,
        "products": "[
            {\"count\":2,\"id\":1,\"price\":275,\"name\":\"Kayak\"},
            {\"count\":1,\"id\":2,\"price\":48.95,\"name\":\"Lifejacket\"}
        ]"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "dzimi",
        "street": "dzimi strit",
        "city": "belgrade",
        "state": "zemun",
        "zip": "11000",
        "country": "serbia",
        "giftwrap": null,
        "products": "[
            {\"count\":5,\"id\":1,\"price\":275,\"name\":\"Kayak\"},
            {\"count\":3,\"id\":2,\"price\":48.95,\"name\":\"Lifejacket\"},
            {\"count\":4,\"id\":3,\"price\":19.5,\"name\":\"Soccer Ball\"}
        ]"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "mimi",
        "street": "cincar janka 7",
        "city": "novi sad",
        "state": "novi sad",
        "zip": "11000",
        "country": "serbia",
        "giftwrap": null,
        "products": "[
            {\"count\":2,\"id\":1,\"price\":275,\"name\":\"Kayak\"},
            {\"count\":1,\"id\":2,\"price\":48.95,\"name\":\"Lifejacket\"}
        ]"
    }
]
```

However when I loop thru it like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <td>{{ order.products.length }}</td>
</tr>
```

I get `100, 153, 100` as results (respectively), and I am expecting `2,3,2` because that is how many objects there are inside each `products`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because products holds a string value and not an array, so you are getting the character length returned for the string values.

The products need to be in the format of:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "dzimi",
    "street": "dzimi strit",
    "city": "belgrade",
    "state": "zemun",
    "zip": "11000",
    "country": "serbia",
    "giftwrap": null,
    "products": [
            {"count":5,"id":1,"price":275,"name":"Kayak"},
            {"count":3,"id":2,"price":48.95,"name":"Lifejacket"},
            {"count":4,"id":3,"price":19.5,"name":"Soccer Ball"}
        ]
  }
```

Comment: Good point. I am returning it like so thru a php backend, do you have any advice on how to turn it into an actual array?

Comment: @frc `JSON.parse(...)`

Comment: I dont know about php, but like others here are saying you could use JSON.parse on the products strings values. I just tried this in chrome debugger using what you posted originally and they decode into arrays of objects just fine

Answer (score 0):

The value of `products` are strings, and you are getting the length of the strings. This is an encoding issue, likely from your backend.

You could try to `JSON.parse(order.products).length`

Note that this does not solve the actual issue (which is in the backend). To solve that issue we would need to see the backend code but you should probably make a different question for that (something along: when I encode my json like `this`, I get `that` in my client but I need `that2`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get the length of the array itself, but since you have the `product` value as a string (i.e. surrounded by quotation marks), calling length of a string will simply return the number of characters.

If you want the number of objects inside of the products array, try *removing the quotes* surrounding the products array, and keep your code the same. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Either you should change the response from the API, or should parse the `string` to `JSON`

```
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
      <td>{{ JSON.parse(order.products).length }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a JSON.parse() before every products value:

```
    // .............
    // .............
    "country": "Serbia",
    "giftwrap": null,
    "products": JSON.parse("[
        {\"count\":2,\"id\":1,\"price\":275,\"name\":\"Kayak\"},
        {\"count\":1,\"id\":2,\"price\":48.95,\"name\":\"Lifejacket\"}
    ]")
},
{
    // ............
```

Working jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/newjavaonemahesh/hso9e375/19/